# How to remove directory referred to by QDir

Tags: c++, qt4

I have a `QDir` referencing an empty directory (it's verified that the directory is empty), and I want to delete the directory from disk. `rmdir` and `rmpath` both take a name/path argument. My first attempt:

```
QDir dir = whatever();
dir.rmdir(".");
```

This works fine on Windows, but fails to remove the directory on Linux. So I had to change my code to this:

```
QDir dir = whatever();
const auto name = dir.dirName();
dir.cdUp();
dir.rmdir(name);
```

This works on both platforms, but seems rather convoluted for an operation as simple as "remove the resource you're referring to." Am I missing a more straightforward way?

Please note that I am currently limited to Qt 4. My current version is 4.8.7.

Comment: @nwp I haven't tried it, but I should hope not; `d.rmdir(x)` is supposed to remove the (child) directory `x` within the directory `d`. In cases such as `C:\foo\foo`, how would `QDir f("C:\foo"); f.rmdir("foo");` distinguish between parent and child?

Comment: @nwp `dirName()` returns the last component of the path only. I can't imagine `d.rmdir(x)` interpreting a relative `x` as relative to something else than the directory referenced by `d`. I *will* try `d.rmdir(d.absolutePath())`, though. Didn't occur to me to use absolute an path.

Comment: The posix standard does not allow removing paths which have `.` or `..` as the last component. See https://unix.stackexchange.com/q/289385.